# Custom icon on Tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) with a ViewPager.

Is there a way I can change the Tab icons dynamically, depending on some actions. Like when a notification is received, I want to change the icon on notifications tab to show how many notifications are unread.

Or any other library which would support that without much tweaking.

Comment: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip is this something you are looking for?

Comment: Like the question says, that is what I am using. But the library doesn't have a way to change icons dynamically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it by implementing `PagerSlidingTabStrip.CustomTabProvider` interface. I made [example project](https://github.com/rom4ek/CustomPagerSlidingTabStrip) for your case, so let's explore it step by step.

**Firstly,** create a layout for our tab called `tab_layout`, for example. It will contain 2 `TextView`'s for title and badge. In my case it looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tab_title"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/badge_background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Secondly,** create a simple model for Tab, that will containt a tab title and number of notifications. I've called it `ViewPagerTab`:

```
public class ViewPagerTab {
    public String title;
    public int notifications;

    public ViewPagerTab(String title, int notifications) {
        this.title = title;
        this.notifications = notifications;
    }
}
```

**Thirdly,** implement `PagerSlidingTabStrip.CustomTabProvider` interface on your `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Here we will inflate tab layout and initialize the tab views, also we will define fragments for positions:

```
public class MainAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.CustomTabProvider {

    ArrayList<ViewPagerTab> tabs;

    public MainAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<ViewPagerTab> tabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabs = tabs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getCustomTabView(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        RelativeLayout tabLayout = (RelativeLayout)
                LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);

        TextView tabTitle = (TextView) tabLayout.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        TextView badge = (TextView) tabLayout.findViewById(R.id.badge);

        ViewPagerTab tab = tabs.get(i);

        tabTitle.setText(tab.title.toUpperCase());
        if (tab.notifications > 0) {
            badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            badge.setText(String.valueOf(tab.notifications));
        } else {
            badge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return tabLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void tabSelected(View view) {
        //if you don't want badges disappear when you select tab comment next lines
        RelativeLayout tabLayout = (RelativeLayout) view;
        TextView badge = (TextView) tabLayout.findViewById(R.id.badge);
        badge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void tabUnselected(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new OneFragment();
            case 1:
                return new TwoFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ThreeFragment();
        }
        return new OneFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.size();
    }
}
```

**Fourthly,** initialize tabs and pager in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    ArrayList<ViewPagerTab> tabsList = new ArrayList<>();
    tabsList.add(new ViewPagerTab("One", 0));
    tabsList.add(new ViewPagerTab("Two", 1));
    tabsList.add(new ViewPagerTab("Three", 2));

    adapter = new MainAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabsList);

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

You will get something like this:
[image]

And **finally**, to get and change tab views in runtime, you can simply call `getChildAt` function of `PagerSlidingTabStrip` object in your `Activity` or `Fragment`, and do what you want:

```
private void notifyTabStripChanged(int position, int notificationsCount) {
    LinearLayout tabHost = (LinearLayout) tabs.getChildAt(0);
    RelativeLayout tabLayout = (RelativeLayout) tabHost.getChildAt(position);
    TextView badge = (TextView) tabLayout.findViewById(R.id.badge);
    if (notificationsCount > 0) {
        badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        badge.setText(String.valueOf(notificationsCount));
    } else {
        badge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**Don't forget**, that child views count is starting from 0. If you want to use images, just replace `ImageView` with `TextView` badge and change it's image resource instead of text. Enjoy!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your project and the explanation. Helped a lot. Will accept it, but I did it a different way - I changed the function `addIconTab(final int position, int resId)` to inflate a custom view instead of `ImageButton`. And in the fragment where I am using the `PagerSlidingTabStrip`, I get the tab using `getChildtAt()` and set the text or hide it as I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome! It's your choice, but I consider that `IconTabProvider` is created for tabs with icons only, when `CustomTabProvider` is created for full customizable tab. Anyways, glad to help you:)

Comment: On smaller devices the tab text goes different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by forking this lib and change the behaviour of IconTabProvider used [there](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample/QuickContactFragment.java) in sample app implemented to use only static resources.

---

Changes to do to your lib fork to add dynamic icon changes:

In `PagerSlidingTabStrip`:

Change return type (and name) of getPageIconResId method of IconTabProvider interface

```
public interface IconTabProvider {
    //public int getPageIconResId(int position) becomes
    public Bitmap getPageIconBitmap(int position)
}
```

This causes to update the call to this method in `PagerSlidingTabStrip`

--

And also to change the method `addIconTab` from

```
private void addIconTab(final int position, int resId) {
    ImageButton tab = new ImageButton(getContext());
    tab.setImageResource(resId);
    addTab(position, tab);
}
```

to

```
private void addIconTab(final int position, bitmap icon) {
    ImageButton tab = new ImageButton(getContext());
    tab.setImageBitmap(icon);
    addTab(position, tab);
}
```

---

Then you need to create an adapter for your tabs bar, here is an example:

```
public class DynamicIconPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements IconTabProvider {

    public HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> mapBetweenPositionAndIcons = new HashMap();

    public DynamicIconPagerAdapter () {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mapBetweenPositionAndIcons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getPageIconResId(int position) {
        return mapBetweenPositionAndIcons.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // looks a little bit messy here
        TextView v = new TextView(getActivity());
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_window);
        v.setText("PAGE " + (position + 1));
        final int padding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
        v.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        container.addView(v, 0);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object view) {
        container.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object o) {
        return v == ((View) o);
    }

}
```

---

Finally, when you want to update an icon just change the corresponding bitmap of the map (mapBetweenPositionAndIcons) and call notifyDataSetChanged() on your PagerSlidingTabStrip object.

I havn't tested my solution yet due to a lack of time, but I will as soon as possible! ;)